# Whats wrong with my snake plant?

Tags: houseplants

I’m new to house plants, so I decided to go with a snake plant. When I got it the leaves were droopy like someone did it dirty as hell. Since I got it Ive repotted it but little cuts are appearing and white spots. Could it be an insect infestation? [image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The older leaves on the snake plant (curling and droopy at the ends) suggest that the plant was previously grown in very low light and the plant may have been somewhat dehydrated as well. The newer growth looks very healthy. I suspect that your plant is now putting out new roots and growth in response to the new conditions that you have given it. The resulting growth spurt may have cause a few cracks to form on the older stunted leaves as they expand in response to the better conditions. You are probably seeing a few "age related" blemishes on the older growth as well which may now be more noticeable. These are nothing to worry about.